# Installing fancyimpute python 3.6

Tags: python

I'm using Windows 10.

While doing `pip install fancyimpute` :

```
Failed building wheel for ecos
      Running setup.py clean for ecos
    Failed to build ecos
    Installing collected packages: dill, multiprocess, ecos, cvxpy, fancyimpute
      Found existing installation: dill 0.2.5
        DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (dill) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
        Uninstalling dill-0.2.5:
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 538, in move
        os.rename(src, real_dst)
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\dill-0.2.5-py3.6.egg-info' -> 'C:\\Users\\Archit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-hir5dush-uninstall\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\dill-0.2.5-py3.6.egg-info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 553, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\dill-0.2.5-py3.6.egg-info'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are likely running into permission problems because you are trying to install the library globally. Your options are either:

1. Run `pip` as an administrator (run your command prompt as administrator, then use that to run `pip`).
2. Use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to install the library locally.

Comment: Command "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Archit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-4lgy1kiw\\ecos\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Archit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-lfuku2jk-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Archit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4lgy1kiw\ecos\      ::: Now This is the error

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I ran conda install ecos. Then I ran pip install fancyimpute in admin. mode.